# Why is it true that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, then $1_H=1_G$?

Tags: group-theory

I am studying about subgroup. My definition of subgroup is that:

Let a set $G$, with a binary operation$
×:G×G→G,(a,b)↦×(a,b)=:a×b$ be a group.　Then $H⊂G$ is a subgroup iff $H$ with a restriction of $×$ to $H×H$, that is,$×|_{H×H}$　is also a group.

And my book states that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, then $1_H=1_G$. Why is this true?

Comment: Note that for every $h\in H$, $h1_G = h = h1_H$. Multiplying by $h^{-1}$ on the left, you get $1_G=1_H$.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun I am reading the Japanese book by Yukie Akihiko in 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to see this:

1. If $h\in H$, then $h=h1_H = h1_G$. From $h1_H=h1_G$, multiply by $h^{-1}$ on the left to get $1_H=1_G$.

   Note that the final product happens in $G$, not in $H$. As you note in comments, if we do not know yet that $1_H=1_G$, then we don't know that the inverse of $h$ in $H$ is necessarily the same as the inverse of $h$ in $G$; but we still have $h1_H=h1_G$ *in $G$*, from which we get $1_H=1_G$ as elements of $G$.
2. In $G$, the only element that satisfies $xx=x$ is $x=1_G$. Since $1_H1_H=1_H$, and this holds inside $G$ as well, that means $1_H=1_G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question about 1. Why $h^{-1}$ with respect to $×$ is always equal to that with respect to $×|_{H×H}$？

Comment: @Saito: You may not know it yet, but it doesn't matter. That final step happens in $G$.

Comment: ... and another downvote. Whoever the person with the personal grudge is, well done.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I didn't ignore Mr. Nico. His answer is so perfect for me that I have no question about his.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose exists $b\in G,b\ne 1_H$ such that $ab=a$ for some $a\in G.$ By multipling $a^{-1}$ on the left we have that $b=1_G$, but $1_H$ is an element of $G$ which satisies $a1_H=a$ for some $a\in G,$ (in particular, the elements of H). Therefore, $1_H=1_G$.